# Understanding of url-patterns in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I was really confused by this parts of web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.labwork.filter.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is the real problem. For example, I have several Servlets and static html pages. All request to them pass through filter. May be, i want to forward to servlet/html page from filter. How can i do this, if all request will be forward to filter? Or, may be, i don't understand principles.

Comment: All the request will be forwarded to the filter, _then_ to your servlet/html if they passed the condition you provided on your filter.

Comment: @lxcky it provided by chain.doFilter? and how can i explicitly forward to servlet / html ?

Comment: Do you mean you want some request to go directly to their servlet/html pages and not go to the filter? If so, you should limit your url-pattern. `/*` means every request.

Comment: @lxcky No, I want all my request go throw filter. But i wan't specify in filter explicitly which servlet / html i want to forward.

Comment: Alright, let me compose an answer and see if it works out for you.

Comment: If I understand correctly,for url pattern of filter rather than '/*',you can have filtering for servlets and direct to html pages directly,theby bypassing filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comment section, you want to filter every request with an exception of a few pages.

Let's say you want to exempt the `login.html` from filtering, what you could do is get the request URI and check if that string contains `login.html` like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {                
    String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
    if (path.contains("login.html")) //login page                                                
        chain.doFilter(request, response); //proceed to the page
    } else {            
        //conditions here
    }
}
```

I must state though that this is not the standard practice. If you're doing this then you should review your design choices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify which servlet/html the request should be forwarded to, you can add `<servlet-name>` and `<servlet-mapping>` sections in your web.xml.

For example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>examples.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

OR

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/login.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```